# Azure powershell command to get the port of a vm

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the port of a vm in azure through powershell command. We are not able to get any command for that, so please suggest us any azure powershell commands for it.

Comment: What port? waiting for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get-AzureEndpoint for that:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "MyTestVM1" -Name "MyTestVM2" | Get-AzureEndpoint
```

[image]